# Knitr weird problem with output languages

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, rnotebook

So I'm doing a report using Rmarkdown in Rstudio. Naturally, using Knitr to get the outputs. For the PDF output, I installed the tinytex package.

The report is in english, so I'd like the date format to be in english.

This is the start of the document:

```YAML
---
title: "MyTitle"
subtitle: "Assignment 3"
date: "`r as.character(Sys.time(), '%d %B')`"
author: "MyName"
output:

  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    theme: paper
    highlight: tango
  pdf_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---
```

I put that command there to automatically get the present date.

Now to the funny part. If I click in "preview notebook" on the Knitr dropdown menu, it shows:

```
MyTitle
Assignment 3
MyName
27 February
First, the csv with the data is read.
```

Mind the language of the month, this is important. The language here is english. All good.
Now if I want to output it in PDF or HTML I get:

```
MyTitle
Assignment 3
MyName
27 fevereiro
First, the csv with the data is read.
```

The month language is now in portuguese, which I suppose is the language got installed in. Also my keyboard language, if that matters.

Question is: How can I have an english output on PDFs and HTML?
Thanks

========================

## Found an answer!

My SO is windows 10.

1. I went to the Windows Settings window, choose "Time and Language"
2. Clicked on the "Region" button on the left hand side
3. Chose "English (Germany)" on the drop-down menu 'Current format' under the 'Regional Format' part.

Wish this is useful to someone who reads this question in the future :)

Comment: Try running `Sys.setenv(LANG="en")` before knitting.

Comment: Thanks, but no, same result. Also tried "English" and "english".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Found an answer!

My SO is windows 10.

1. I went to the Windows Settings window, choose "Time and Language"
2. Clicked on the "Region" button on the left hand side
3. Chose "English (Germany)" on the drop-down menu 'Current format' under the 'Regional Format' part.

Wish this is useful to someone who reads this question in the future :)